# Ошибка при установке своего расширения для FireFox 38.0.1

Tags: linux, firefox, webbrowser

Ситуация такая - есть машина на линуксе с мазилой 38.0.1 (без доступа в интернет и usb), пользователь монотонно выполняет одно и тоже действие, решено было написать свой user-script + расширение, со скриптом проблем не возникло,(как собственно и с расширением, но для гугла) а вот с установкой расширения в браузер, выдает ошибку про повреждение файла, что делать?
что сделано уже:

1. формат .xpi (+ правильная иерархия файлов)
2. добавлял с ключом browser_specific_settings и applications
3. about:config и его настройки не помогают
4. оно без проблем запускается на гугле

```
{
  "name": "App1",
  "description": "App1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

p.s. естественно если бы была возможность запуска через debug - вопрос не стоял
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]